# JQuery without parameters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently work with [great bindings for knockoutjs and kendo UI created by Ryan Niemeyer](http://rniemeyer.github.io/knockout-kendo/) and I tried figure out some features in the javascript code.

What exactly JQuery do when we pass no arguments like that:

```
if (!$()["kendoComboBox"]) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, this checks for availability of the plugin. `$()` creates an 'empty' (i.e., without DOM elements wrapped) jQuery object, then its `kendoComboBox` property is checked. If its value is falsy, or the property is just not defined (either on object itself or in its prototype chain), the branch is executed.

However, I'm really not sure how exactly it's better than checking jQuery.prototype directly:

```
if (!('kendoComboBox' in $.fn)) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very. I just don't figured out the extension of telerik in $.fn and about empty jquery object.